# On upper bounds on the distance between the population density and a chosen density

Tags: probability, distributions

Say One has a certain number of observations from a population density $p(x)$ and based on the observations decides to utilize a density $q(x)$ to approximate the unknown population density $p(x)$.

Can one choose $q(x)$ in such a way to get some upper bound for the $L^2$ distance or $L^1$ distance between the two densities:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} (p(x) - q(x))^2 \, dx \qquad \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} |p(x) - q(x)| \, dx$$

so that one can estimate how far off he can be on his approximation of the unknown population density?

Comment: No, you can assign discontinuities to the density on a set of measure zero that are arbitrarily large and the density estimator will never converge to those values.

Comment: @AdamO what if we assume the population density is well behaved? there are no results in this sense?

Comment: Are you assuming that the functional form of $p(x)$ is known and that the only issue is parameter estimation for a finite-dimensional set of parameters?

Comment: @jbowman  unfortunaly I am not making assumptions on the the functional form of $p(x)$, for example if I choose $q(x)$ as the empirical density function then I know as the sample grows to infinity that $q(x)$ and $p(x)$ will become closer to each other, is there a bound on the distance the two distribution as the function of the sample size? something like this. I hope I am explaining myself.